# Android build shrinking native library file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, java-native-interface

For reference: I am building using Android Studio 2.2 on OS X.  My colleagues are building using Android Studio 2.2 on linux and Windows.

Problem: When building an APK with native libraries, I'm finding that on OS X one of the .so files is being shrunk/modified during the build process.  This is not happening on Windows or Linux.  The result of this is that my app won't function properly as the required library fails to load properly at runtime.  The odd thing is that this is only happening to one of the .so files (always the same one) and not to any of the others used by the app.

When comparing the apk's produced by different platforms we can always see this ->

[image]

Decompressing the AKP and looking at the file it has indeed been reduced in size somehow.

Looking back through the project I see that the file in the jniLibs folder is the correct size, as is the file in build/intermediates/jniLibs - but when it gets into the APK it is smaller.

Has anyone seen this happen before?  Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: might be because of optmizations, refer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/LqTTFK__On0

Comment: Don't think that is it.  We are using 'provided' .so files - so we are not compiling code using the NDK ourselves.

Comment: yes of course, but this might be happening because of build optimization, have you checked the build logs?

Comment: Nothing there to suggest anything unusual is happening.  However I've gone through the process of decompiling the apk, replacing the file in question, and then rebuilding and signing the new APK - and everything works.  So something is knocking 20 bytes off the file somewhere during build for no reason.